# Get JSON from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf, servlets

I'm using $.ajax to get data sent to servlet but seem all data return with symbol char

```
var dataJson = {"title":"sss","message":"dddd","latLon":"(-30.410781790845874, 129.375)","address":"Maralinga SA 5710, Australia"} ;

$.ajax({
      url: 'http://mydomain/servler/call1',
      type: 'POST',                                     
      data:{
          data: JSON.stringify(datajson)
      },                                        
      dataType: 'json',
      success:function(results) {alert(results);
}
});
```

And my "call1" servlet

```
 response.setContentType("application/json");     

 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
 String json = "";
 json = br.readLine();
 log.info("Result Data json: " + json);

===> Result Data json:  %7B%22title%22%3A%22%22%2C%22message%22%3A%22%22%2C%22latLon%22%3A%22(-41.442726377672116%2C+143.26171875)%22%2C%22address%22%3A%22Oodnadatta+SA+5734%2C+Australia%22%7D
```

I dont know why my web service response data with strange data....:|

Comment: If you're talking about the `%` stuff, it is the standard way to encode characters in HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When data is sent throught the request, your browser converts some character to its hexadecimal representation, escaped with a `%` symbol.

If you want to read it with Java, you need to decode the string you get. The package `java.net.URLDecoder.decode` should do the trick.

Try the following code:

```
response.setContentType("application/json");     

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
String json = "";
json = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(br.readLine(), "UTF-8");
log.info("Result Data json: " + json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Antonio,

My ex:

```
   String fileName = "Map%20of%20All%20projects.pdf";  
   fileName = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(fileName, "UTF-8");
   System.out.print(fileName);
```